# limit memory usage of users on windows server 2008 r2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, memory-usage

We have an IBM server in our research lab with Windows server 2008 R2 OS. Six users log in and use software like MATLAB or R and run their codes. When a bad program takes up too much RAM or CPU usage, the serve hangs and RDP disconnects. How do I solve this issue?
I have enabled per_user resource management. But when 3 users all write code that require say, 3GB of memory, the problem still occurs. I believe I have to also limit the maximum usage permitted for all users.

Please advice.

Config: Windows Server 2008 R2
Proc: Intel Xeon E5-2640 (2 processors)
RAM: 64 GB

Comment: Have you thought just adding RAM? It sounds from your numbers you run a larger desktop - not even a workstation. My smallest servers have 32gb memory and seriously, that did cost nearly nothing.

Comment: Sorry, that was just an illustration. Its an enterprise server with intel Xeon E5 series processors and 64GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Windows System Resource Manager](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2009/12/08/windows-system-resource-manager-wsrm-does-exactly-what-it-says-on-the-tin.aspx) you can set limits for CPU and memory usage using rules which can specify process, user and group on Windows 2008 r2.

Comment: Thanks. I have put a per_user limit for both CPU and memory. Is there a way to cap the usage for all user processes, so that RDP is always functioning?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent RDP crash, you can add all the users to a group and limit RAM usage for that group with Resource Manager.